# Mysql minimum and maximum values of "rate" for each month

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with two fields - a field for "date" entered as day/month/year and a field "rate"

> date | rate
>
> 24/01/05 | 1.9754
> 26/01/05 | 1.3723
> ...
> and so on

So, I like to find  minimum and maximum values of "rate" for each month of year(s). My query selects only one row

> SELECT  DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%y') as Date, MIN(rate) as r, MAX(rate) as mr FROM rates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will get the rate values for each month and year

```
SELECT
    YEAR(date) AS thisYear,
    MONTH(date) AS thisMonth,
    MIN(rate) AS minRate,
    MAX(rate) AS maxRate
FROM rates
GROUP BY thisYear ASC, thisMonth ASC
```

If you need to have the individual date(s) on which the min or max occurs you'll need some additional grouping in there, however the above should suffice for your original question.

Comment: how can I get individual dates of max and min?

Comment: @mustafa: as long as you have `min` and `max` value - you can just perform additional query with trivial `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

To get the minimum and maximum values of "rate" for each month of year, you can modify the query as follows:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m-%Y') as Month_Year, MIN(rate) as Min_Rate, MAX(rate) as Max_Rate
FROM rates
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m-%Y');
```

The `GROUP BY` clause groups the rows in the rates table based on the month and year of the date field. The `MIN` and `MAX` functions then calculate the minimum and maximum values of the rate field for each group. The `DATE_FORMAT` function is used to format the date field into a string with the format `%m-%Y`, where `%m` is the month (01-12) and `%Y` is the year (e.g., 2005).

This query will return a result set with one row for each unique month and year in the rates table, along with the minimum and maximum values of the rate field for that month and year.